# Como usar uma variavel do PHP no javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Tem como declarar uma variavel no PHP e depois utiliza-la no JavaScript?

Exemplo:

```
<?
    var w_qtd_v = 0;
?>

<script language="javascript">
    w_qtd_v = w_qtd_v + 1;
</script>
```

Comment: Você pode jogar o valor do php em um input hidden ou passar esse valor para uma função js. Esse js precisa executar quando a página é carregada ou em outro evento?

Comment: O primeiro bloco é php? Não parece.

Comment: <script>
  var variavelJavascript = "<?php echo variavelPHP ?>";
</script>

Comment: @bfavaretto, o primeiro bloco foi só um exemplo de como eu quero que "seja"

Comment: @perdeu o js vai ser executado quando eu chamar uma function, para ter uma atribuição. Por isso queria declarar a variavel no PHP para ela não zerar sempre que eu entrar no JS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O javascript não tem como atualizar o valor da variavel PHP, somente o php manipula/cria o JS. Para fazer este update, você vai precisar de um ajax, logo depois de ter alterado o valor da variável com JS...caso seja essa a questão.

O PHP corre do lado do servidor para criar a página, e o JS corre do lado do cliente com a página já criada. A unica maneira deles "falarem" é via ajax.

Se estiver utilizando um framework, como zend e etc, você geralmente utiliza um template engine para trabalhar com variáveis no HTML, podendo tambem passar estas variáveis para o JS, exemplo de uso de variaveis com o template engine [RainTpl](https://github.com/rainphp/raintpl3)

index.php

```
// include
require "library/Rain/autoload.php";
// namespace
use Rain\Tpl;

$config = array(
    "tpl_dir"   => "vendor/rain/raintpl/templates/test/",
    "cache_dir" => "vendor/rain/raintpl/cache/"
);

Tpl::configure( $config );

$t = new Tpl;
$t->assign('title','Hello!');
$t->draw('test');
```

test.html

```
<html>
...
<p>
{$title}
</p>
</html>

<script language="javascript">
    var title = "{$title}";
</script>
```

ou simplesmente faz assim

```
<?php

$title = "Hello";

?>
<script language="javascript">
    var title = "<?php print $title; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Muito bom o que me passou William! Mas como no meu caso eu pretendo utilizar a variável declarada no PHP como um iterador, como ficaria?

Comment: não sei se entendi, mais com template engine, passa o valor da variável pelo método $t->assign('title','Hello!'); onde o primeiro parâmetro é o nome da variavel eo segundo é o seu valor, assign tbm pode receber um array

Comment: o javascript não tem como atualizar o valor da variavel PHP, somente o php manipula o JS, para fazer este update, você vai precisar de um ajax, logo depois de ter alterado o valor da variável com JS...caso seja essa a questão.

Comment: Huum' agora sim você respondeu minha duvida !

Comment: @WilliamBorba juntei o seu comentário e mais algumas palavras na resposta. Corrija se achar mal.

Comment: @Alexandre se o William respondeu à sua pergunta pode marcar a resposta como aceite.

Comment: Ele respondeu no comentário! Não na área de respostas ^^

Comment: @Sergio vlw, obrigado por contribuir na resposta :)

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim:

```
<?php
$variavel = "texto";
?>


<script>
  var variavel = "<?php echo $variavel; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Rene, seria ideal juntar uma explicação sobre porque o código da pergunta não funciona. Ou seja, falar sobre a diferença entre PHP e JavaScript em termos de client/server side.

Comment: Concordo, @Sergio. Vejo muitas perguntas por aí sem nenhuma informação. Achei essa por exemplo pesquisando por "Tente assim"

Answer (score 2):

O PHP e o Apache são responsáveis por interpretar a página php e enviar de volta pro cliente, navegador do usuário, o código html e neste processo o php pode enviar código javascript dentro do html de acordo com o processamento.

Entretanto, dependendo do caso, isso pode ser feito através de uma requisição AJAX onde o JS vai enviar pro servidor um pedido e obter uma resposta, assincronamente, sem interromper a sua aplicação. E dai, com essa resposta no JS, você pode fazer o que quiser.

Referëncias:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100633/change-php-variable-based-on-javascript-value
- http://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar passar da seguinte maneira (exemplo chamando um método do PHP para passar para o JS):

```
<?php 
        $usuario = AutenticacaoUsuarioLogado::usuariologado();

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "    var usuario = " . $usuario . ";";
        echo "</script>";        
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

tbm pode tentar assim

```
<?php
$nameemphp = "Ola mundo";
echo "<script>var nameemjs = '".$nameemphp."';</script>";
?>
```

Ele atribui uma variável php para uma variável em javascript, utilizando o concatenamento para adicionar a variavel no echo.