# Valor do php no javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

A ideia e essa abaixo, mais nao esta dando certo quando eu coloco o valor da variável do php direto no javascript, por exemplo`-3,3462, -60,6790` ai funciona, sabem o que poderia ser?

```html
<?php 
$variavel = "-3,3462, -60,6790";
?>

<script> 

var testMarker = L.marker([<?php $variavel;?>],{icon: orangeIcon});  

</script>
```

Comment: Atenção que você ao passar o valor `[-3,3462, -60,6790]` irá ficar com o seguinte `Array [ -3, 3462, -60, 6790 ]`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como usar uma variavel do PHP no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28673/como-usar-uma-variavel-do-php-no-javascript)

Comment: Possível quintuplicata...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mude:
`<?php $variavel;?>`

Para:
`<?php echo $variavel;?>`

```js
<?php 
$variavel = "-3,3462, -60,6790";
?>

<script> 

var testMarker = L.marker([<?php echo $variavel;?>],{icon: orangeIcon});  

</script>
```

Comment: Também pode utilizar `<?= $variavel ?>` como alternativa ao `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua variável for um array, faça dessa forma:

```
<?php 
  $variavel = ["-3,3462", "-60,6790"];
?>

<script> 

var testMarker = L.marker([<?php echo $variavel[0];?>,<?php echo $variavel[1];?>],{icon: orangeIcon});  
</script>
```

Comment: Aparentemente é só uma string mesmo. Também pode utilizar `<?= $variavel ?>` como alternativa ao `echo`.

Comment: Mas se existir a possibilidade de ser um array, pode fazer `<?= json_encode($variavel) ?>` que a saída será `[..., ..., ...]`.