# Como utilizar variáveis PHP em JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho uma variável quantidade, e tenho duas *tags* `<a>` que funcionam como `onclick` e chamam a função `myFunc1` ou `myFunc2`. Uma serve para aumentar a quantidade e outra para diminuir. a myFunc1 para diminuir e a myFunc2 para aumentar.

`<a onclick='myFunc1()' style='font-size:18px' id='diminuir' class='fa'>&#xf147;</a>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunc1() {
    var oldValue = <?php echo json_encode($quantidade)?>;
    if (oldValue > 0) {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 0;
    }
    <?php echo json_encode($quantidade)?>; = newVal;
  }

  function myFunc2() {
    var oldValue = <?php echo json_encode($quantidade)?>;
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    <?php echo json_encode($quantidade)?> = newVal;

    <?php echo json_encode($quantidade)?>; = newVal;
  }
</script>
```

quero que as tags  aumentem e diminuam a variavel quantidade, e pelo que eu vi a unica forma que eu vi para fazer isso é com o onclick, e para fazer a função quero passar a variavel quantidade que é php, aumentá-la com javascript e voltar a converte-la para php

Mas este código não está a funcionar, o problema é da diferenciação das variáveis, da *tag* ou de qualquer outra coisa?

Comment: Explique com palavras o que tentou fazer aí, porque o código não fez sentido algum.

Comment: Se estiver numa página php, o código `var oldValue = <?php echo json_encode($quantidade)?>` vai funcionar, porém esse outro código não faz sentido `<?php echo json_encode($quantidade)?> = newVal`. Já pensou no que irá aparecer no meio do código `javascript`? algo como `1 == newVal`, e o que isso iria fazer?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss já editei lá

Comment: Mas você quer incrementar/decrementar o valor no JS e jogar isso na variável PHP? Isso não é possível. Leia sobre *frontend* e *backend* para entender melhor. Um executa no lado do cliente; outro no servidor. A única forma deles se comunicarem é via mensagens por um protocolo de comunicação (HTTP, no geral). Se quer fazer o JS *conversar* com o PHP, use AJAX.

Comment: quero que as tags <a> aumentem e diminuam a variavel quantidade, e pelo que eu vi a unica forma que eu vi para fazer isso é com o onclick, e para fazer a função quero passar a variavel quantidade que é php, aumentá-la com javascript e voltar a converte-la para php

Comment: Estás a mostrar a quantidade em algum lugar da página? Como o Anderson Carlos Woss disse, para passar a nova quantidade para o PHP tens de enviar esse valor para o servidor, e para isso podes usar AJAX. Se quiseres visualmente mudar a quantidade na página, isso é possível com Javascript só, mas, vais ter de enviar para o servidor em algum momento para o PHP saber esse novo valor.

Comment: @Leite sim exato eu quero mudar o valor da variavel, não apenas visualmente

Comment: edshewa, isso que você quer não é possível desta forma.
Para você aumentar o valor de sua variável no PHP você precisa fazer uma requisição para o servidor (PHP) que será o responsável por aumentar este valor.

Comment: Vais ter que seguir a sugestão do Anderson Carlos Woss então. Ou se quiseres sugestões sobre que caminho seguir, tens de colocar mais informação na pergunta. Dá para perceber o que queres fazer, e com o código que tens, não é possível. Mas com mais detalhe pode alguém te ajudar a encontrar o caminho correcto.

Comment: Outra coisa para você estudar: HTTP não retem estado (é [*stateless*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119549/5878)). Então, o que o PHP fará com o novo valor?

Comment: Como exemplo, quando estás a ver um carrinho de compras e tens os itens e a quantidade. Por vezes dá para mudar essa quantidade, e às vezes também com botões, mas para depois o servidor saber o novo valor, há um botão que vai submeter essas novas quantidades para o servidor. Por exemplo os campos assim, https://en.helpforsite.com/image/cache/catalog/products/ajax_quantity_for_journal2_cart-1280x1280.png e depois haveria um botão que não se ve ai para enviar para o servidor.

Comment: @leite como assim um botão que não se vê?

Comment: Não se ve na imagem do link, mas seria visível para quem ve a página. Essa imagem é só um exemplo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Igualar variável php a uma variável javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25136/igualar-vari%c3%a1vel-php-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-javascript)

Comment: Outra pergunta no mesmo estilo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28673/132

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim: escreva exatamente o seguinte num arquivo pagina.php,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Minha pagina</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
    $q = 0;
    if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['q'])) {
        echo "<h1>A sessão q no lado servidor vale {$_POST['q']}</h1>";
        $_SESSION['q'] = $_POST['q'];
        $q = $_SESSION['q'];
    }

    // Salva q em algum lugar.
    // salvar($q);
?>
    <form method="post" id="f">
      <label for="inc">Incrementa</label><input type="button" value="Aperte para incrementar" id="inc" /><br />
      <label for="dec">Decrementa</label><input type="button" value="Aperte para decrementar" id="dec" /><br />
      <label for="u">Valor no lado cliente:</label><input type="text" name="q" id="u" readonly="readonly" value="<?= $q ?>" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#inc').on('click', function () {
            var u = +$('#u').val();
            $('#u').val(++u);
            this.form.submit();
        });
        $('#dec').on('click', function () {
            var u = +$('#u').val();
            if (u) {
                $('#u').val(--u);
            }
            this.form.submit();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

execute e veja o comportamento.